# How to pass images into fpdf

Tags: php, image, dynamic, fpdf

I'm trying to figure out how to pass specific images from a website to make a pdf with fpdf.  I can get fpdf creation working, but can't figure out how to grab images from the page and put them into fpdf.

The ideal is that I'll have a set of images: A, B, C, D, etc.  The user clicks on B and D and then clicks on "create pdf" and the pdf is images B and D on separate pages.

I can figure out everything except for passing images B and D to fpdf. Can you point me in the right direction?

I'm not tied to fpdf in particular; it just seems to be a popular choice for php pdf creation.

Comment: How do the users select the images? Is it in a form and does that redirect to another page for pdf creation?

Comment: When they click the image, it gets a new class.  I could make the selected images go into a form with jquery.